# Odoo related field not updating if store=True

Tags: odoo

I've defined a new field on the `product.product` model using the UI in Odoo V10. The field is defined like this:

```
Name = x_sellable_inventory
Type = float
Readonly = true
Dependencies = qty_available,outgoing_qty
```

the Compute method is:

```
for record in self:
    record['x_sellable_inventory'] = record.qty_available - record.outgoing_qty
```

I added this field to a view and confirmed that it's changing correctly if the on-hand inventory is adjusted for the product. So far everything is working as expected.

Now, I want to be able to access this value from a `sale.order.line`, so I created a related field on the `sale.order.line` to access it. It's defined like this:

```
Name =  x_product_sellable_inventory_new
Type = float
Readonly = true
Stored = true
Related Field = product_id.x_sellable_inventory
```

I then added this field to the sale order view so I can see it in the list of order lines. It appears once for each order line in the tree.

Now, when I change the on-hand quantity for the product, it still updates correctly on the product view, but the value on the sale order line never changes. It never changes from that initial time it was set.

If I uncheck the `Store` option, the value gets updated correctly. What is happening here? Why does it matter if the related field is Stored or not? Shouldn't it get updated whenever the value of `product_id.x_sellable_inventory` changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my issues here was that the fields I was trying to use as dependencies were not `stored` themselves. It seems that the fields need to be stored in order to function correctly as dependencies, which makes sense. The model has no way of knowing the dependent field has changed if it's not a field that is stored in the database. `qty_available` and `outgoing_qty` are not stored fields.

Answer (score 3):

Computed fields are not stored by default. Which you know. This causes issues when you wish to be able to perform functions which require the data be available in the database.

To fix this Odoo provides the store=True flag on a computed field.

The `gotcha` is that it only fires once. In order to get around this you need to use the `@api.depends` decorator (as @danidee and @CZoellner had stated) in order to have your field updated every time your related field or fields is changed.

`@api.depends` can also receive a comma separated list of field names.

`@api.depends('field_name')`

OR

`@api.depends('field_name','another_field_name')`

```
@api.one
@api.depends('field2')
def _compute_field1(self):
    self.field1 = SOMETHING THAT OCCURS EVERY TIME `field2` CHANGES


field1 = fields.Char(compute=_compute_field1,store=True)
field2 = fields.Char()
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm asking about a `related` field, not `computed`. Does that make a difference? According to these docs: http://odoo-new-api-guide-line.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#related-field it says: "Setting the store kwarg will automatically store the value in database. With new API the value of the related field will be automatically updated, sweet." What am I missing here? Additionally, doesn't your answer mean that dependencies on computed fields are irrelevant if `store=True`? Since the field never auto-recomputes itself, the dependencies changing have no effect.

Comment: I am not sure whether the docs are correct or not. However I believe the principle still stands. You should be able to update the field you wish using some variation of this workaround. My understanding is that store=True only fires once. Regardless of what the docs say.

Comment: So do dependencies serve no purpose on a stored computed field? I'm new to Odoo, trying to learn all these intricacies. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe the end result is that they do not. Many (including myself) have been frustrated trying to code around these complexities.

Comment: Which means dependencies serve no purpose at all because the field is either calculated in real-time when its requested, or calculated once when the record is created. So dependencies do nothing at all. Something isn't adding up here.

Comment: Dependencies are working just right. I had never problems with new API computed fields so far. Of course there are some limitations. If i recall correct there is or was a bug/limitation on related computed fields.

Comment: No @PhillipStack stored fields can still be re-computed if they're decorated with `@api.depends`. Just did some a few days ago and i confirm that it works :)

Comment: I just checked this @danidee, and you are right. I think this slipped my mind. I have seen some weird hacks to get certain field relations to work properly and for whatever reason thought this was one of those situations. I tested and found your suggestion is correct. I have updated the answer as to not mislead people. Thanks!